# Extract all positive and negative integers in a string in Perl

Tags: perl, scripting

I want to extract all positive and negative integers in a string using Perl. The string contains the following character and spaces - , { }

Eg :

```
$a = "{ { 0,256,0,0 },{ -2,256,2,0 },{ -4,256,4,0 },{ -6,255,7,0 }
     ,{ -7,254,10,-1 },{ -8,252,13,-1 },{ -10,251,16,-1 }
     ,{ -10,249,19,-2 },{ -12,247,23,-2 },{ -14,245,27,-2 }
     ,{ -14,242,31,-3 },{ -15,239,35,-3 },{ -15,236,39,-4 }
     ,{ -16,233,44,-5 },{ -17,230,48,-5 },{ -17,226,53,-6 }
     ,{ -18,222,58,-6 },{ -18,218,63,-7 }";
```

my o/p should be array `@b` containing 0, 256,0,0,-2,256,2,0 ... etc as its elements

I have tried the following command but spaces/null elements are also added to my o/p array.

```
my @b = split (/[,{}\s]/,$a);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When extracting, you often want to look for what you *do* want, instead of splitting on what you don't want. Try a global regex match for this case:

```
# Match each integer-like value, including sign:
my @b = $a =~ /-?\d+/g;
```

Seems to do the trick.